# Trouble exporting map from RTAB-Map

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, 2d-mapping, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/217097/export-2d-map-from-rviz-andor-rtab-map/) answer to export a `.pgm` and a `.yaml` from a database file generated using RTAB-map.

But when I run

> rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap _database_path:=IROS14-kinect-challenge.db

I get a message saying that `/rtabmap` did not receive any data since 5 seconds. I know there is no data being published into `/odom`,
`/rgb/image`,
`/depth/image`,`/rgb/camera_info`

but shouldn't this data be coming from the database file?

When I run

> rosrun map_server map_saver map:=proj_map

I get this message:

> [ INFO] [1551154609.903198676]: Waiting for the map

and

> rosservice call /publish_map 1 1 0

doesn't do anything.

- I am running ROS melodic on Linux Mint(Ubuntu 18.04).
- I have downloaded the  IROS14-kinect-challenge.db file from  [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B46akLGdg-uaeFFWUUZWX2hsaVE&authuser=0)
- I have double checked that roscore is running. :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316634/trouble-exporting-map-from-rtab-map/) by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on ROS Kinetic, but rtabmap is the same version than on Melodic and I cannot reproduce the problem. Following exactly what you did, after doing `rosservice call /publish_map 1 1 0`, I see in the rtabmap_ros terminal:

```
[ INFO] [1551304861.803715934]: rtabmap: Publishing map...
[ WARN] [1551304862.123340986]: Many occupancy grids should be loaded (~698), this may take a while to update the map(s)...
[ WARN] [1551304872.284061124]: Map(s) updated! (10.160718 s)
[ WARN] [1551304872.284428237]: /proj_map topic is deprecated! Subscribe to /grid_map topic instead.
```

so the map is created, then on map_server terminal, I can see:

```
$ rosrun map_server map_saver map:=proj_map
[ INFO] [1551304856.764290592]: Waiting for the map
[ INFO] [1551304872.285442346]: Received a 551 X 447 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[ INFO] [1551304872.285460183]: Writing map occupancy data to map.pgm
[ INFO] [1551304872.289321822]: Writing map occupancy data to map.yaml
[ INFO] [1551304872.289390615]: Done
```

The map created:
[image: image description]

The warnings that it did not receive any data since 5 seconds are normal, as no sensors are publishing topics to rtabmap.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on 2019-02-27**:
Ah, looks like I just needed to wait a bit :D
Thanks for your response.